# How to train test split custom dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have an image dataset with four classes(folders) inside it ...upto loading the dataset is not a problem.. my problem is how to take dependent and independent variables so that I can split up the dataset for further processing

dataset="path/"
Categories=["A","B","C","D"]
My problem is how to proceed after loading the dataset so that I could perform onehot encoding to all the four classes
I am a very begginer in this field...so any help will do thankyou

Answer (score 0):

**If you split the image dataset into train, test, and validation then many way to do this.**
*suppose, it is your folder structure.*

```bash
$ tree dataset

dataset/
  |
  |-- A (folder)
  |   |
  |   |--> image1.jpeg
  |   |--> image2.jpeg
  |
  |-- B (folder)
  |   |
  |   |--> image1.jpeg
  |   |--> image2.jpeg
  |
  |-- C (folder)
  |   |
  |   |--> image1.jpeg
  |   |--> image2.jpeg
  |
  |-- D (folder)
  |   |
  |   |--> image1.jpeg
  |   |--> image2.jpeg
  |
```

it is a function for spliting the dataset `python`

```py
import random
import os
import shutil

def split(main_path:str, from_path:str, size:float=0.2, shuffle=True) -> any:
    file = []
    for i in os.listdir(main_path):
        file.append(os.path.join(main_path, i))

    if shuffle:
        random.shuffle(file)   # For shuffling the file path

    sizes = round(size * int(len(file)))   # Calculating the Dataset
    for i in range(sizes):
        shutil.move(file[int(i), from_path)  # For moving the File from another Directory

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PATH = "/new_dataset"  # Enter New Dataset Path
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(PATH, "Validation"))
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(PATH, "Test"))
        for i in os.listdir(PATH):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(PATH, "Validation" ,i))
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(PATH, "Test" ,i))
    except FileExistsError:
          pass
       
    for i in os.listdir("/dataset"):
        split(os.path.join("/dataset", i), os.path.join(PATH, "Validation", i), size=0.2, shuffle=True)
    for i in os.listdir("/dataset"):
        split(os.path.join("/dataset", i), os.path.join(PATH, "Validation", i), size=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

**And, the remind folder change it name `dataset` to 'train' and move it on '/new_dataset' directory. Each Directory Contain Random Images**

```bash
$ tree new_dataset

new_dataset/
  |
  |-- Train (folder) # /dataset
  |   |
  |   |--> A
  |   |--> B
  |   |--> C
  |   |--> D
  |
  |-- Test (folder)
  |   |
  |   |--> A
  |   |--> B
  |   |--> C
  |   |--> D
  |
  |-- Validation (folder)
  |   |
  |   |--> A
  |   |--> B
  |   |--> C
  |   |--> D
  |
```